# while writing in a file few data is missing

Tags: java, file

I am getting some data in list which further I am writting in a file on fly
there are two list and they have croos joi and that file is writtenin a file through buffered writer as shown now the problem is that complete data is not written in a file that is 
there are total 907864 lines then 905864 line are there , please advise why fe lines are missing while I am writting the file...

```
File file = new File(FilePath + getFileName());
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }



            BufferedWriter bw = new  BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));


            for (Posuser posuser : totalusers) {
                for (potook bk : books) {

                    if ((posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null)
                            && (posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null)) {

                        bw.write("aaa"+"\r\n");

                    } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null
                            && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() != null) {
                        bw.write("bbb+"\r\n");


                    } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() != null
                            && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null) {
                        bw.write("ccc"+"\r\n");


                    }

                    else
                        bw.write("ddd"+\r\n");


                }

            }

            bw.flush();
            bw.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: can this code snippet be compiled successfully?

Comment: bw.write("bbb+"\r\n"); Your missing a quotation mark there...

bw.write("ddd"\r\n"); and a + sign there...

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. why are you splitting string literals into two? (e.g "bbb" + "\r\n"). I don't see how that really improves readability and in your case, even cause you to make a few syntax errors. Why not just use "bbb\r\n"?

Comment: @cpu i have done that the causae of worry is why complete data is not written that was the main focus

Comment: @RamKumar Well... It makes no difference regarding your issue.

Comment: @RamKumar: Did any solution help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be deleting the created/existing file

```
 if (file.exists()) {
     file.delete();
  }
```

Alternative would be:

```
if(!file.createNewFile()){
    System.out.println("File Exists");
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand please explain in detail

Comment: [java doc buffered Writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: @boxed__l BufferedWriter extends java.io.Writer which has a write(String) method.

[java.io.Writer Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: if (!file.exists()) {
     file.createNewFile();
    }

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that this is happening because your code doesn't reliably flush the output:

```
    try {
        ....
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

If *any* exception is thrown in the "..." section, then the `flush` and `close` calls won't be executed.  Instead, the method will (most likely) jump to the handler for `Exception` and log the error.

The correct way to write this is you want to be sure that the output is flushed / closed is like this:

```
    File file = new File(FilePath + getFileName());
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new  BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        for (Posuser posuser : totalusers) {
            for (potook bk : books) {
                if ((posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null)
                        && (posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null)) {
                    bw.write("aaa"+"\r\n");
                } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() == null
                        && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() != null) {
                    bw.write("bbb+"\r\n");
                } else if (posuser.getUpdatedBy() != null
                        && posuser.getUpdateddateformat() == null) {
                    bw.write("ccc"+"\r\n");
                } else {
                    bw.write("ddd"+\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException, AnotherException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Notes:

1. I am using Java 7 "try with resources" syntax, which *automatically* closes the *resource* object ... in this case the `BufferedWriter`. That's why there is no explicit `close()`.  (If you can't use Java 7, then do the `close()` in a `finally` block.
2. It is not necessary to `flush()` AND `close()`.  Closing a `BufferedWriter` implicitly flushes and buffered data first.
3. Don't catch `Exception`.  Catch the checked exceptions and *specific* unchecked exceptions that you are expecting.  If you catch `Exception`, you are liable to catch an mishandle exceptions that are actually a result of bugs.
4. Just logging the exception and continuing as if nothing had happened is *probably* a bad idea ...

---

In addition, the code at the beginning to delete the file if it exists is unnecessary.  When you open a file the way you are doing, it will truncate an existing file if there is one.

Comment: thanks a lot for the expnation but the where the flush and close of buffered writer should be